# Moving away from ROOT user

Tags: security, users, root, ownership

I've recently been asked to help out a friend with some server and website issues they have been having, nothing major really.

However I found out that since the day they got their VPS everything, including uploading files, installing wordpress, all FTP, everything has been done through root.

So I am wondering what is the best way to fix everything to make it more secure?

The reason im asking is because im assuming its more than just make a new non-root user to use for day to day stuff? Due to how everything has been set up and ownerships already with every other file etc

Answer (score 1):

That is a bad mess.

- I think you should create three users: one for day-to-day use (lets call this `user`, one for the web server (usually one is created when you install Apache, usually called `www-data`) and one for the FTP server (call this `ftp`), all with accompanying groups of the same name.
- Add `user` to both `www-data` and `ftp` groups. `chown` the web directory to be owned by `user:www-data`, and make it `setgid` and `setuid` (`chmod ug+s`). Do the same for the FTP upload directory, but with `user:ftp`.
- If the FTP upload and Wordpress media directory are the same, make a third group with all three users in it (call it `upload`, and chown the directory `user:upload`.
- The web server is usually running as `www-data`, unless they deliberately went and changed it. You will have to configure the FTP server (usually `vsftpd`) to run as the `ftp` user.
- Make sure all the relevant directories are `setgid` so that they inherit group permissions. You can make the `setuid` as well. (Only the directories, note!)
- Restrict day to day stuff to `user`. Make sure `www-data` does not have write permissions where it has no business having them.

Beyond this, I am not really qualified to give security advice.